# Why can't I apply property to my own custom class in extjs4?

Tags: extjs4.1

Can someone help me out to resolve the problem that I'm not able to apply some of properties to my own custom class. Here is my source:

```
Ext.define('com.amkor.web.common.client.GridPanel', {
alias : 'Web.common.client.GridPanel',
extend : 'Ext.grid.Panel',
isCheckbox : false,
initComponent : function(){ 
    var me = this;
    var sm = (me.isCheckbox)?Ext.create('Ext.selection.CheckboxModel'):'';          
    Ext.apply(me, {
        title : 'Grid',
        width : 560,
        height : 300,
        selModel : sm,
        frame : false,
        border : false,
        forceFit : true,
        columnLines : true,
        autoLoad : false,
        autoDestory : true
    });     
    me.callParent(arguments);
},
getGridSelection : function(){
    return this.getSelectionModel().getSelection();
},
removeGridSelection : function(){
    this.getStore().remove(this.getGridSelection());
}
});
```

As you see, I defined new custom class by extending `Ext.grid.Panel`, and then I define new custom class by extending custom class `com.amkor.web.common.client.GridPanel`.

```
Ext.define('EvaluationApp.view.EvaluationGrid', {
extend : 'com.amkor.web.common.client.GridPanel',
xtype : 'EnhancementGrid',
initComponent : function(){
    Ext.apply(this, {
        id : 'evalGrid',
        width : 556,
        height : 290,
        title : 'Wow',
        columns : columns,
        features : [Ext.create('Ext.grid.feature.Grouping', {
            groupHeaderTpl : '<div align="left">연도 : <font color="green">{[values.rows[0].grp_year]}</font> ({rows.length}) </div>'
        })]
    });
    this.callParent(arguments);
}
});
```

I wanted to change title from "Grid" to "Wow", but it does not apply.
Please give me some advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Ext.define('com.amkor.web.common.client.GridPanel', {
    alias : 'Web.common.client.GridPanel',
    extend : 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    isCheckbox : false,

    title: 'Grid',

    initComponent : function(){ 
        var me = this;
        var sm = (me.isCheckbox)?Ext.create('Ext.selection.CheckboxModel'):'';          
        Ext.apply(me, {
            width : 560,
            height : 300,
            selModel : sm,
            frame : false,
            border : false,
            forceFit : true,
            columnLines : true,
            autoLoad : false,
            autoDestory : true
        });     
        me.callParent(arguments);
    },
    getGridSelection : function(){
        return this.getSelectionModel().getSelection();
    },
    removeGridSelection : function(){
        this.getStore().remove(this.getGridSelection());
    }
});
```

Notice how I moved the title config from inside the `Ext.apply` to the class definition. Now, when this grid is created, if a title is passed in, that title will be used. If no title is passed in, the title will default to `'Grid'`.

To understand what is happening here, you need to understand what `Ext.apply` is doing. `Ext.apply` takes the second object passed in, and copies its properties onto the first object passed in. More info can be found in the docs: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext-method-apply .

So, in the code above, `Ext.apply` is copying properties onto `me` (which equals `this`), and is taking those properties from the object you are passing in as the second argument, which is displayed below.

```
{
    width : 560,
    height : 300,
    selModel : sm,
    frame : false,
    border : false,
    forceFit : true,
    columnLines : true,
    autoLoad : false,
    autoDestory : true
}
```

So, anything listed in the above object will overwrite the same properties found in `this`. When you create or extend the above class, any properties added to it (such as your example of setting `title: 'Wow'`) will be added directly to `this`. As I said before, any properties defined in the second object will overwrite anything defined in `this`, so that is why when you put `title: 'Grid'` in the second object, it just overwrote any `title` property you passed in when extending the class.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It resolved. I really appreciate for you. Would you please do me a favor ? one is what is the principle ? the other is what is the "arguments" that is used by "callParent".

Comment: I will answer the first question by adding more info to my answer. As for the second question: in JavaScript, `arguments` is all the arguments passed to a function. This variable is available in all JavaScript functions. See this link for more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments

Comment: Also, if my answer fixed your issue, then you should accept it as the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Would you let me know how to accept answer? I am new to stackoverflow -:)

Comment: Just click the green checkmark beside my answer. See this link for more info. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235

Comment: I'm done. pls check it out and let me know if I'm wrong. I'm really thankful for you.